# Running more than 5 pig and deadlock

Tags: apache-pig, oozie

I am running more than 3 pig scripts at the same time. However, all the workflows are held. I checked the log file. It always pop up "heart beat".

My workflow is running on only one namenode. I check the problem on website. It seems that I can configure mapred.job.queue.name. However, I am not sure how to use it.

Could you please give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with small clusters.

Every time oozie runs a workflow it generates a launcher job which is responsible for launching the different actions written in the workflow. This job is created before the first actions is run and will end after the last action is finished.

This means that if you started 6 oozie jobs you have already 6 map slots taken without doing any real work at all.

A possible solution for this would be to run launcher jobs on a separate launcher queue rather than the default queue.
you can do this by setting this part in the pig action inside your oozie workflow.xml

```
 <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>oozie.launcher.mapred.job.queue.name</name>
      <value>launcherqueue</value>
    </property>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you ran out of free mapper or reducer slots on jobtracker. Try to increase values of  'mapred.map.tasks' and 'mapred.reduce.tasks' in mapred-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried to submit your pig script away of using Oozie. I tried to use bash script and it worked fine. For example:

```
pig -f /path/to/pig/scripts/script1.pig -param input=inputValue &
pig -f /path/to/pig/scripts/script2.pig -param input=inputValue &
.
.
.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi `Heart beat` error is occurs due to **insufficient Total memory** size in *Hadoop*. This because you may run in small cluster machine.

**Solution**: So you want to increase the size of Total memory to all nodemanager to perform mapreduce job. Steps are followed in this link ["HEART BEAT ERROR SOLUTION"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27855432/3452185)