# Heartbeat print on running R script via Oozie

Tags: r, oozie, heartbeat

I was trying to run a R script on Oozie.
Though the R script was triggered, the Oozie job kept printing Heartbeat in the stdout file, without proceeding further into the R-code.
What may have caused it? Also, how to avoid the same?

#### Edit :

The script was supposed to read data from HDFS and a series of R scripts were supposed to be operating on the data to generate a json output.
The script was triggered by the oozie workflow from command line.
This oozie job is further planned to be exposed as an API.

I have tried changing the scheduler to fair scheduler as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653937/error-on-running-multiple-workflow-in-oozie-4-1-0/27855432#27855432) post, but still it didnt work.

Comment: Please offer more details. How did you run that script? What is that script? What is the output?

Comment: @ArashKazemi, edited the question to incorporate more details